# Getting the value out of a Future in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet that I use to read a record from the database and I'm using ReactiveMongo for this.

```
val futureList: Future[Option[BSONDocument]] = collection.find(query).cursor[BSONDocument].headOption

val os: Future[Option[Exam]] = futureList.map {
  (list: Option[BSONDocument]) => list match {
    case Some(examBSON) => {
      val id = examBSON.getAs[Int]("id").get
      val text = examBSON.getAs[String]("text").get
      val description = examBSON.getAs[String]("description").get
      val totalQuestions = examBSON.getAs[Int]("totalQuestions").get
      val passingScore = examBSON.getAs[Int]("passingScore").get
      Some(Exam(id, text, description, totalQuestions, passingScore))
    }
    case None => None
  }
}.recover {
  case t: Throwable => // Log exception
  None
}
```

I do not want to change my method signature to return a Future. I want to get the value inside the Future and return it to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need then to block using the awaitable object:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val os: Future[Option[Exam]] = ???
val result = Await.result(os, 10 seconds)
result.getOrElse(/* some default */)
```

Note that blocking will block the thread until the future is completed or the timeout expires and an exception is thrown, note also that this kinda defeats the purpose of having async computation, but it may be ok depending on your use case.

If you don't need the result immediately you can attach a callback using `onComplete`

```
os onComplete {
  case Success(someOption) => myMethod(someOption)
  case Failure(t) => println("Error)
}
```

Note that `onComplete` will be fired only when the future is completed so the result is not immediately accessible, also the return type is `Unit`.

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of using Future in my opinion. I see that there is a method called value that gives me an Option of Try of an Option.

Comment: Using `value` will return `None` if the future is not completed, and some result if it is, not sure you want that honestly.

Comment: The real problem is what you are asking I think, you want the result of some async computation without blocking, you see already form the sentence that this is illogical, async computation will return a result (or not) in the future (the name is pretty indicative), if you want to wait for that result you have to... well wait and block, there's really no other way around it. Depending on what you want to do with the result you can use a callback like `onComplete`, but that depends on your needs.