# How to retrieve value from the output of a scala Future?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to query a table, store values of the query in a Scala Map & return the same map.
To do that, I came up with the following code:

```
def getBounds(incLogIdMap:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]): Future[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]] = Future {
  var boundsMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
  incLogIdMap.keys.foreach(table => if(!incLogIdMap(table).contains("INVALID")) {
    val minMax    = s"select max(cast(to_char(update_tms,'yyyyddmmhhmmss') as bigint)) maxTms, min(cast(to_char(update_tms,'yyyyddmmhhmmss') as bigint)) minTms from queue.${table} where key_ids in (${incLogIdMap(table)})"
    val boundsDF  = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", commonParams.getGpConUrl()).option("dbtable", s"(${minMax}) as ctids")
      .option("user", commonParams.getGpUserName()).option("password", commonParams.getGpPwd()).load()
    val maxTms = boundsDF.select("minTms").head.getLong(0).toString + "," + boundsDF.select("maxTms").head.getLong(0).toString
    boundsMap += (table -> maxTms)
  }
  )
  boundsMap
}
```

In order to receive the value from the method: `getBounds`, I used the method `onCompletion` as below:

```
val tmsobj    = new MinMaxVals(spark, commonParams)
val boundsMap = tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds)
boundsMap.onComplete({
  case Success(value) =>
  case Failure(value) =>
})
```

I have coded in Scala before but I am new to `Futures` in Scala. Could anyone let me know how can I retrieve the value returned by `getBounds` into  `val boundsMap`

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898494/getting-the-value-out-of-a-future-in-scala

Comment: I saw your answer where you mentioned "accessing a value from a Future is not recommended as it defeats the purpose of asynchronous computation". In that case, how can I apply Future on a method and use the value returned by it ? Feeling a bit confused due to my lack of knowledge on Futures.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if that answers your question

Comment: @Chaitanya, Read your answer but I got confused with other burning doubts like -> if the value of a Future is not recommended to be retrieved, how/when do I access the result of a Future ? If the purpose of Future is to run a thread/process independent of main thread, why is it that it is not recommended to access it ?
Will the Future automatically assign its output to its caller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Awaits ( not the best aproach)

```
val boundsMap = Await.result(tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds),Duration.Inf)
```

Or use the value only when you need

```
val boundsMap = tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds)
booundsMap.map(value => Smth_To_Do(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a value from a Future is not recommended as it defeats the purpose of asynchronous computation. However, there may be cases where you are dealing with the legacy code or some situation where fetching the value from the future is the way forward. To deal with such situations, there are two approaches

1. Using await that will block the thread

> ```
> Await.result(getBounds, 10 seconds)
> ```

So, here what await does is, it will wait for 10 seconds for the getBounds future to complete. If it completes within this time, then you have the value, else you get an exception here. The biggest drawback of this method is that it blocks the current thread of execution.

2. Using a callback method `onComplete` as you have used

> ```
> getBounds onComplete {
>    case Success(someOption) => myMethod(someOption)
>        case Failure(t) => println("Error)
>      }
> ```

So what onComplete does is to register a callback function that will get executed whenever the future is completed. This is comparatively safer that await.
You can refer to [Accessing value returned by scala futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures) for further details.

I hope that this answers your question.

Comment: Is this the right way to call the function: getBounds ->
    val tmsobj    = new MinMaxVals(spark, commonParams)
    tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds) onComplete ({
      case Success(Map)   => val boundsMap = tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds)
      case Failure(value) => println("Future failed..")
    })